# Trying to issue tokens on testnet with python API - Neblio

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, blockchain, neblio

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.TestnetNTP1Api()
body = swagger_client.IssueTokenRequest() # IssueTokenRequest | Object representing the token to be created

try:
    # Builds a transaction that issues a new NTP1 Token
    body.issue_address(issue_address="TUfp4Ss95xaKQPNGpbiZDsMPe4NR16CDiL")
    body.amount(1000)
    body.divisibility(0)
    body.fee(1000000000)    
    body.reissuable(False)
    body.metadata({"token_name": "STST", "issuer": "Septio", "description": "Septio_Test"})    
    api_response = api_instance.testnet_issue_token(body)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling NTP1Api->issue_token: %s\n" % e)
```

Im trying to have fun testing possibilities of NEBL, issuing tokens and stuff like that. What am i doing wrong?

I get such error:

> raise ValueError("Invalid value for `issue_address`, must not be
>   `None`")  # noqa: E501
>
> ValueError: Invalid value for `issue_address`, must not be `None`

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for asking the first Neblio SO question!

We sorted this out on discord. Metadata naming the token is required and the API docs need to be updated to reflect this.

You want something like this:

```
body = swagger_client.IssueTokenRequest(
    issue_address = "TUfp4Ss95xaKQPNGpbiZDsMPe4NR16CDiL",
    amount = 10000, 
    divisibility = 0,
    fee = 1000030000, 
    reissuable = False,
    metadata = swagger_client.IssueTokenRequestMetadata(
        token_name = "TEST",
        issuer = "Me",
        description = "My test token"
    )   
)  # IssueTokenRequest | Object representing the token to be created
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at - [documentation here](https://github.com/NeblioTeam/neblio-api-lib-python/blob/master/docs/IssueTokenRequest.md) I think you need to change the assignment as

`body.issue_address = "TUfp4Ss95xaKQPNGpbiZDsMPe4NR16CDiL"`

Also try this format, by looking at other assignments.

`body.issue_address("TUfp4Ss95xaKQPNGpbiZDsMPe4NR16CDiL")`